# Using protoc from yocto build rather than host system

Tags: linux, makefile, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

Im trying to port grpc c++ example code to yocto build. Im using yocto 2.2(morty). currently I'm able to integrate protobuf 3.3.0 and grpc 1.4.3 into yocto build. Using older versions because I all the layers are from morty branch. Here is my recipe hello.bb.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Working example for grpc"
AUTHOR = ""
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
HOMEPAGE = ""
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/Apache-2.0;md5=89aea4e17d99a7cacdbeed46a0096b10"

DEPENDS = "grpc golang protobuf3 c-ares zlib openssl"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libstdc++"

SRCREV = "29a2a533c98aa21f05c8f598ef2b47321508d5da"
BRANCH = "v1.4.x"
SRC_URI = "gitsm://github.com/grpc/grpc.git;protocol=https;name=grpc;branch=${BRANCH}"

PR = "r0"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"


EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DRUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX=1 \
     -DRUN_HAVE_POSIX_REGEX=0 \
     -DRUN_HAVE_STEADY_CLOCK=0 \
     -DTHREADS_PTHREAD_ARG=2 \
     -DBUILD_DEPS=ON \
     -DHAVE_STD_REGEX=ON \
     -DRUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX=1 \
     "

do_compile() {
  cd ${S}/examples/cpp/helloworld/
  make all
}


FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/*"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_client ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_server ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Im using the Makefile from the [git](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.4.x/examples/cpp/helloworld/Makefile). I have modified to fix few paths . So my current Makefile is

```
HOST_SYSTEM = $(shell uname | cut -f 1 -d_)
SYSTEM ?= $(HOST_SYSTEM)
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS += -I/home/src/build/tmp/work/armv5e-linux-gnueabi/protobuf3/3.3.0-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/include/ -pthread
CXXFLAGS += -I/home/src/build/tmp/work/armv5e-linux-gnueabi/protobuf3/3.3.0-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/ -pthread
#CPPFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include -pthread
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
LDFLAGS += -L/home/src/build/tmp/work/armv5e-linux-gnueabi/grpc/1.4.3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib `pkg-config --libs grpc++ grpc`       \
           -lgrpc++_reflection \
           -lprotobuf -lpthread -ldl
else
LDFLAGS += -L/home/src/build/tmp/work/armv5e-linux-gnueabi/grpc/1.4.3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib `pkg-config --libs grpc++ grpc`       \
           -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed \
           -lprotobuf -lpthread -ldl
endif

PROTOC = protoc
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN = grpc_cpp_plugin
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH = "/home/src/build/tmp/work/armv5e-linux-gnueabi/hello/1.4.3-r0/git/vsprojects/vcxproj/"
PROTOS_PATH = ../../protos

vpath %.proto $(PROTOS_PATH)

all: system-check greeter_client greeter_server

greeter_client: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_client.o
        $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

greeter_server: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_server.o
        $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@


.PRECIOUS: %.grpc.pb.cc
%.grpc.pb.cc: %.proto
        $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH) $<

.PRECIOUS: %.pb.cc
%.pb.cc: %.proto
        $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --cpp_out=. $<

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.pb.cc *.pb.h greeter_client greeter_server


# The following is to test your system and ensure a smoother experience.
# They are by no means necessary to actually compile a grpc-enabled software.

PROTOC_CMD = which $(PROTOC)
PROTOC_CHECK_CMD = $(PROTOC) --version | grep -q libprotoc.3
PLUGIN_CHECK_CMD = which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
HAS_PROTOC = $(shell $(PROTOC_CMD) > /dev/null && echo true || echo false)
ifeq ($(HAS_PROTOC),true)
HAS_VALID_PROTOC = $(shell $(PROTOC_CHECK_CMD) 2> /dev/null && echo true || echo false)
endif
HAS_PLUGIN = $(shell $(PLUGIN_CHECK_CMD) > /dev/null && echo true || echo false)

SYSTEM_OK = false
ifeq ($(HAS_VALID_PROTOC),true)
ifeq ($(HAS_PLUGIN),true)
SYSTEM_OK = true
endif
endif

system-check:
ifneq ($(HAS_VALID_PROTOC),true)
        @echo " DEPENDENCY ERROR"
        @echo
        @echo "You don't have protoc 3.0.0 installed in your path."
        @echo "Please install Google protocol buffers 3.0.0 and its compiler."
        @echo "You can find it here:"
        @echo
        @echo "   https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0"
        @echo
        @echo "Here is what I get when trying to evaluate your version of protoc:"
        @echo
        -$(PROTOC) --version
        @echo
        @echo
endif
ifneq ($(HAS_PLUGIN),true)
        @echo " DEPENDENCY ERROR"
        @echo
        @echo "You don't have the grpc c++ protobuf plugin installed in your path."
        @echo "Please install grpc. You can find it here:"
        @echo
        @echo "   https://github.com/grpc/grpc"
        @echo
        @echo "Here is what I get when trying to detect if you have the plugin:"
        @echo
        -which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
        @echo
        @echo
endif
ifneq ($(SYSTEM_OK),true)
        @false
endif
```

So the problem im facing is when the make file runs protoc command it uses the protoc from my host machine instead of yocto build. i.e 3.21.12 version which raises error with the protobuf (3.3.0) from yocto build as

> | In file included from helloworld.pb.cc:4:0:
> | helloworld.pb.h:10:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/port_def.inc: No such file or directory
> |  #include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
> |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> | compilation terminated.
> | : recipe for target 'helloworld.pb.o' failed
> | make: *** [helloworld.pb.o] Error 1
> | WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.

I have tried to use protoc command in hello.bb recipe, It also uses from host machine.

So is there a way to use protoc from yocto build in Makefile?

Comment: The `sysroot-destdir` folder is for recipe output. It is pretty much empty until the do_populate_sysroot step, which is one of the last ones after the compilation. Your required files are either in `recipe-sysroot` (for target components) or in `recipe-sysroot-native` (for native components).
At the very first step, what happens if you revert your Makefile changes, and add `grpc-native` to the dependencies?

Comment: @skandigraun Thanks. But i dont have recipie for grpc-native. I need to write it. But can i know the reason to use grpc-native here instead of grpc. sorry im too new to software and yocto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using protobuf-native as dependency solves this issue. As native build provides tool during build time. Hence protoc was available during build time.